# Does PHP have an exposed implementation for abstract interfaces?

Tags: php, oop, abstract

The concept I'm thinking of comes from the [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface. This interface cannot be directly implemented, but instead is satisfied by implementing an interface that extends it.

Can I declare an interface that cannot be implemented and instead extend with public interfaces?

**Edit:** I realize the possibility would be rather pointless as it could be circumvented by a third party creating an interface that could extend the base interface. I'm looking for a cleaner way to express polymorphism.

For example:

```
abstract interface Vehicle
{
}

interface Car extends Vehicle
{
    public function drive(RouteProvider $routeProvider, $speed)
}

interface Boat extends Vehicle
{
    public function sail(BodyOfWater $water, $heading);
}

class PeopleMover
{
    public function move(Vehicle $vehicle)
    {
        if ($vehicle instanceof Boat) {
            // move people across bodies of water
        } elseif ($vehicle instanceof Car) {
            // move people along roads
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't, but could you not just declare an normal empty `Vehicle` interface and achieve the same thing? You're relying on third parties not extending/implementing it anyway.

Comment: weird example. why don't you give a common name for the methods?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath because the example is rather simplified, the methods would take different required arguments. e.g. the `drive` method probably takes a route discovery service and the `sail` method might need to know the body of water. The two objects in my example might be too close to represent what I do.  `Traversable` with `Iterator` and `IteratorAggregate` is what I want to achieve where they do different things but can reach the same result if you know what you are working with.

Comment: @Bulk that's what I started thinking after I made my edit. I guess I was initially thinking it would be nice for the end user to get some sort of early warning rather than a runtime error, but if they don't have the realization that it isn't going to work then... they may have bigger problems

Comment: @SteveBuzonas I wouldn't worry too much - anyone who implements an empty interface is asking for trouble anyway ;)

Comment: @Bulk a plus for Java I suppose with scoped types, I wonder if hack has scoped types

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of an interface is to define how an application access your object, rather control how objects are defined.  It's a way for your object to state to the application, "I implement this interface, so you can trust I have these methods."

If you want to control how objects are defined, you should use abstract classes with abstract methods.

Comment: I'm not trying to control how it is defined, that's why I want to use an interface.  However I would like to declare that my method accepts similar items that do different things/require different types of arguments to get to the same end goal. polymorphism in a nutshell... i'll take this or that, they don't do the same thing... but i can make them work to achieve the same result

Comment: I think you are slightly off track with polymorphism.  Based on your example, instead of having Car::drive() and Boat::sail(), you would have Vehicle::transport(), with Car and Boat having their own implementation.  Both need the same method signature for transport(), so one parameter would be of type Route, and then you would extend that to include RouteByRoad and RouteByWater.

Comment: That is a correct statement for `inclusion polymorphism` aka `subtyping`.  When discussing my intention of the implementation as a means of function overloading without `parametric polymorphism` it would be `ad-hoc polymorphism` which `subtyping` isn't necessarily a one size fits all solution.  Utilizing my example the `Vehicle` isn't the one responsible for transport, `PeopleMover` is, and the different requirements for different means of transport vary.  Additionally, I wouldn't want a `Chauffer` implementation to think it can fly an `Airplane` just because they can both transport.

Comment: You are right.  So you change things so you can supply a route, and it returns an appropriate vehicle.  I.e. you supply RouteByWater, and you get back Boat. Your code should not need to be aware of what type of route it supplies, nor what type of vehicle is returned, so long as they all share a common interface.  That's polymorphism.  Polymophism is defined as "a pattern in object oriented programming in which classes have different functionality while sharing a common interface."  Your specific example, you have defined a different interface per class, so this is the opposite of polymorphism.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what I want to achieve. I'm not trying to achieve the polymorphism you are thinking of. I want more of a parametric polymorphism like `foreach`, it takes an array, object, or `Traversable`.  `Traversable` has no implementation but is extended by `Iterator` and `IteratorAggregate`. The interfaces `Iterator` and `IteratorAggregate` do not do the same thing, however, `foreach` is a polymorphic method which does the same thing with 4 different input types.